# What is the purpose of quickly moving the speedbrake lever on the 757 during rollout?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing-757

I found two videos where the PF quickly moves the speedbrake lever during rollout on the 757. Note that they are already deployed. Here are the links: [video 1](https://youtu.be/54YXP4NsPqo?t=217) and [video 2](https://youtu.be/7YBALLYcZHc?t=187) (out of view). What is the purpose of doing so?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On B757, B767, B777, retracting the speed brakes during the landing roll is a technique some pilots use to disarm the Auto Brakes. I haven’t flown the other Boeings, but they probably also work this way.

It is especially useful if your Auto-braking is coming on a little too strong and you want to extend your rollout to the next exit.

It is easier than reaching all the way over to the right side of the panel to turn them off.

Pushing hard on the brake pedals will also disarm the Autobrakes, but that is the last thing you want to do when trying to extend your rollout.

Comment: Autobrakes 3 or 4 gives a pretty good deceleration rate, and while applying the brakes will smoothly disarm them, it will add deceleration and further the delay the rollout to a high speed exit. Moving the speedbrake handle just a little bit also smoothly disarms the Autobrakes.

Comment: Somehow not sure if pilots using tricks to make procedures simpler is a good thing

Comment: And that's why generic statements seldom apply to specific circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps "trick" is the wrong word? For example when driving a car, there are a number of ways to disable the cruise control.  All competent drivers know these different ways, and, they use them appropriately.

Comment: Agreed. I just edited “little trick” to “technique”.